# Spring - Using factory-bean types with lookup-method

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Okie is have some third party code running on Spring 3.1.4 and I cannot change that. Also the code uses `lookup-method` to inject a type dynamically at runtime. This type is of a prototype scope. All is standard Spring usage of `lookup-method` based service object creation.
Problem is that on 3.1.4 there is a lot of blocking on `DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry` because of the synchronized block there in `getSingleton` method. The thread dumps show that the execution path reaches there when a `lookup-method` based inject is required and get stuck there till they get the time to run through.

I was wondering if I can use a factory-bean to create those prototype beans instead of defining them as a prototype bean itself. Inside the factory-method of the factory bean i would use the `new constructor_call()` based approach to instantiate the value beans. And also keep the bean id of the `factory-bean` same as the prototype bean in the third party cpring configuration XML.

would this approach work?

Answer (score 0):

> And also keep the bean id of the factory-bean same as the prototype
>   bean in the third party cpring configuration XML.

I don't think this would work.  If you have two beans with the same name (the one you define plus the one presumably defined in the 3rd party's config) you'll get an exception.

However, I think you could use a [BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.html?is-external=true) to [remove the prototype scoped bean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistry.html#removeBeanDefinition(java.lang.String)) and replace it with a bean of your own design.

Comment: this works John but 2 beans with same id is not an elegant solution. You don't get any exception but ht beans are silently overridden. You get an exception or error when 2 beans in the same xml file have the same id. I think that is what it it.